# twisted web for production server service

Tags: python, web, twisted

I would like to deploy several WSGI web applications with Twisted on a debian server, and need some direction for a solid production setup. These applications will be running 24/7.

- I need to run several configurations, each binding to different ports/interfaces/privileges.
- I want to do as much of this in python as possible.
- I do not want to package my applications with a program like 'tap2deb'.

What is the best way to implement each application as a system service? Do I need some /etc/init.d shell scripts, or can I manage this with python? (I don't want anything quite as heavy as Daemontools)

If I use `twistd` to manage most of the configuration/process management, what kind of wrappers/supervisors do I need to put in place?

I would like centralized management, but restricting control to the parent user account is not a problem.

---

The main problem I want to avoid, is having to SSH into my server once a day to restart a blocking/crashed application

Answer (score 0):

I have found several good references for launching daemon processes with python. See `daemoncmd` from pypi.

Im still coming up a little short on the monitoring/alert solutions (in python).

Comment: Why not use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)? Also, consider using a different Python webserver like Tornado or Gunicorn.

Comment: I want to avoid heavy configuration (unless it is implemented in python). I am also hoping for one-stop-configuration per application, so having to deal with nginx and Gunicorn is starting to move in the wrong direction. FYI, I have a completely functional Apache+mod_wsgi deployment right now, but I am looking for something much more flexible.